# Projectile fires from the wrong location

Tags: c#, monogame

I create the projectile when I press the space bar like this

```
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && shoot)
{
    shoot = false;
    this.fire.Play(.2f, .9f, 0);
    lazerX = (float)(spritePosX);
    lazerY = (float)(spritePosY);

    Projectile projectile = new Projectile(heroLazer, "heroLazer",
        lazerX, lazerY, rotationAngle);

    Game1.AddProjectile(projectile);
}
```

then in the Projectiles class the new instance is created like this.

```
public Projectile(Texture2D lazerSprite, string spriteName,
    float posx, float posy, float heading)
{
    projectileSprite = lazerSprite;
    type = spriteName;
    spriteRotOrigin = new Vector2(projectileSprite.Width / 2, projectileSprite.Height / 2);
    spriteHeading = heading;
    spritePosX = posx; // the x position of the lazer
    spritePosY = posy; // the y position of the lazer

    spritePos = new Vector2(spritePosX, spritePosY);
    drawRectangle = new Rectangle((int)spritePosX, (int)spritePosY,
        projectileSprite.Width / 2, projectileSprite.Height / 2);

}
```

updated like this

```
public void update(GameTime gameTime, KeyboardState keyboard)
{
    //projectile active or not?
    if (active == true)
    {
        projectileAge += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;

        spritePosX += (float)(Math.Sin(spriteHeading) *
            gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) * ProjectileMoveAmount;
        spritePosY -= (float)(Math.Cos(spriteHeading) *
            gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds) * ProjectileMoveAmount;

        spritePos = new Vector2(spritePosX, spritePosY);
    }
    if (projectileAge > projectileLife)
    {
        active = false;
    }
}
```

and drawn on screen like this

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(projectileSprite, spritePos, null,
        Color.FromNonPremultiplied(255, 255, 255, 255), spriteHeading,
        spriteRotOrigin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0f);

}
```

[image]

The above code works well EXCEPT that the projectile fires from the CENTER OF THE SPACESHIP.

I can't capture an image which shows the projectile shooting from the center of the spaceship, but it does. What is wrong with my code? My trigonometry is rather weak so please be gentle and give some details.

[image: spaceship facing up and then rotated right 90deg.]

Comment: `lazerX = (float)(spritePosX - (0) * Math.Cos(rotationAngle));` This is equivalent to `lazerX = (float)spritePosX;` 0 * x = 0 for any x.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to remove that code. But it still does not solve the problem. What do i need to do to get the ship to fire from its nozzle?

Comment: Is "spritePosX" and "spritePosY" the center of ship? I think then "0" would just have to have been replaced by ship's width/height ? ... edit: Divided by 2

Comment: if you look at the image above it is the height of the ship which is the radius and keeps rotating. the ship is taller than the width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thank all those who set me on the way. The following simple lines of code solved the problem perfectly.

```
            if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && shoot)
            {
                shoot = false;
                //is.fireInst.Play();
                this.fire.Play(.2f, .9f, 0);
                float newRotAngle = Game1.DegreesToRadians(rotationAngle);

                // the new code

                lazerX = spritePosX + (float)Math.Sin(rotationAngle) * HeroSprite.Width / 2;
                lazerY = spritePosY - (float)Math.Cos(rotationAngle) * HeroSprite.Height/2;

                Projectile projectile = new Projectile(heroLazer, "heroLazer",
                    lazerX, lazerY, rotationAngle);

                Game1.AddProjectile(projectile);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, the problem is that the starting position of your projectile must be adjusted by the size and the rotation of the ship sprite.

I don't know your framework so I can only help you on the concept. If your ship has a rotation of 0 and is facing north, for example, the projectile X must be:

```
 shipSprite.X + (shipSprite.Width * 0.5f)
```

and the projectile Y must be:

```
 shipSprite.Y
```

If the ship is facing west, the projectile X must be:

```
 shipSprite.X
```

and the projectile Y must be:

```
 shipSprite.Y + (shipSprite.Y * 0.5f)
```

And so on...

Comment: I guess that's waht OP is trying to do with `lazerX = (float)(spritePosX - (0) * Math.Cos(rotationAngle)); ` Seems like spritePosX/Y is the center of the ship. Just that "0" should be ship's size, I guess.

Comment: I agree. This is always aligning the position of the lazer to the position of the ship using a zero.

Comment: All points taken. I edited the question and removed the 0. Still the same problem. This code is C# written in Visual Studio 2017. Any suggestions as to how to move the firing position to the top? The above answer makes no sense to me.

Comment: @emorphus Why doesn't it make sense to you?

Comment: I do not undestand what you are saying. Can you use my code and show me how to calculate the firing position to the top? ( I am on C#)

Comment: @emorphus The answer indicates that Belluzzo does not know your framework.  Also, you can't expect others to just fix your code.  You need to be involved in the process.

Comment: I supplied all the code I wrote and even gave a link to the repo on bitbucket. What else can I do? I simply do not know how to ALLIGN THE PROJECTILE to the FRONT OF THE SPACE SHIP.  None of the suggestions work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

(Assuming spritePosX and spritePosY give Ship's position in ship's center and rotationAngle is in **radians** ...)

Your code before edit was *nearly* right:

```
lazerX = (float)(spritePosX - (0) * Math.Cos(rotationAngle));
```

Just that `(0)` doesn't make sense. It should be the ship's size/2 like this:

```
lazerX = (float)(spritePosX - (shipSize * 0.5f) * Math.Cos(rotationAngle));
```

(`shipSize` is the height of the spaceship, so `shipSize * 0.5f` is the radius = distance from ship center to nozzle)

Example:

If "North" is angle of 0° then Cos(0) is 1 =>
lazerX = shipCenterX - shipSize*0.5 * 1

For "East" : 90° Cos(PI/2) = 0 => 
lazerX = shipCenterX - shipSize*0.5 * 0

Accordingly for `lazerY`:

```
lazerY = (float)(spritePosY + (shipSize * 0.5f) * Math.Sin(rotationAngle));
```

This also assumes your coordinate system is:

```
+-----------------------------------------------> y
|
|
|                       ^  - Nozzle      ^ = 0°,  > = 90° , v = 180° , < = 270°
|                       X  - Ship Center
|
|
v

x
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/32txfb

Comment: what is 0.5f? I tried adding half width and half height but didn't work.

Comment: 0.5f is 1/2 float , so x * 0.5f is basically x / 2

Comment: BTW: Math.Cos expects radians. So if you have the angle in degrees you need to do `rad = Math.PI * degrees / 180.0;`

Comment: this doesn't work. the firing position keeps moving . At least in my code it always fired straight out of the nozzle but STARTED OFF AT THE CENTER. I need to figure out a way to move it up to the top which is half the height. Then it is like the radius of a circle because when the ship rotates the height will rotate in a circle around the center of the ship and the firing position is at the radius. How do i add that to the y position?

Comment: Exactly like for X. Just you use `Math.Sin`.

Comment: when i add x and y both the shooting position keeps moving about. As it it is ALWAYS stays in the center. see the new image. it is the height of the ship which is the radius of the circle of rotation. shoudn't that be added? Tan or ATAN2 or something....

Comment: I had a little error there. For X you have to subtract, for Y you have to add. Adding the radius is extactly what size/2 * Math.Cos(angle) does. Also see the fiddle.

Comment: Say you ship's center is at 0,0 and your size is 1, then for 0° you have to do in X: centerX - size * 0.5 * Cos(angleInDegrees * Pi/180) = 0 - 1 * 0.5 * 1 = -0.5 and in Y : centerY + size * 0.5.*Sin(angleInDegrees * PI/180) = 0 + 1 * 0.5 * 0 = 0 => (-0.5,0) - so you get the startpoint size/2 above center for 0°

Answer (score 0):

Writing from head:

```
x=player.x+cos(angle)*z;
y=player.y+sin(angle)*z;
```

Where z is distance from center to top of gun and angle you allready have from player.